# How to modify a state monad?

Tags: haskell

I use State Monad Transformer to manage global state like this

```
data State = State ...
StateT State IO ()
```

And I use `amqp` to consume messages from RabbitMQ. The state will be modified according to messages received. The function has the type like

```
consumeMsgs :: Channel 
            -> Text 
            -> Ack 
            -> ((Message, Envelope) -> IO ())  -- ^ the callback function
            -> IO ConsumerTag
```

Right now we can ignore other parameters but the third which is a callback function I will supply and where the modification happen.

Because it's a mainly IO Monad, so I use this function as follows

```
consumeMsgs chan queue Rmq.Ack (flip evalStateT ssss . rmqCallback)
```

Here the `ssss` is the state I put in and I find that during the process of my callback function `rmqCallback` the state can be correctly modified. But, every time next callback happens the global state is the same as before the consumeMsgs is called or equal with `ssss`.

I understand State Monad is just a process needing an initial state to put in and maintain the state during whole way but has nothing to do with the state out of Monad (am I missing something?),  so I count on MVar to hold and modify the state, and that works. I want to know it's there other way to handle this, maybe another Monad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It looks like you could use [Network.AMQP.Lifted.consumeMsgs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/amqp-0.18.1/Network-AMQP-Lifted.html#v:consumeMsgs). `StateT s IO` is an instance of `MonadBaseControl IO m`, so you could run whole `consumeMsgs` inside single `runStateT`</strike>

Yes, StateT monad transformer is basically a nice notation for a pure code, so if your API accepts only IO callbacks you have no choice but to use "real" state like MVar or IORef etc.

PS: As [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170903/2303202) suggests, the state changes done in [Network.AMQP.Lifted.consumeMsgs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/amqp-0.18.1/Network-AMQP-Lifted.html#v:consumeMsgs)'s callback do not propagate to subsequent callback runs or resulting state. I cannot wrap my head around the implementation, but I tried [liftBaseWith](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.7/monad-control-1.0.2.3/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:liftBaseWith) a bit and it really looks like so.

Answer (score 1):

To add a clarification that might be useful for future reference, the accepted answer is not exact. While `Network.AMQP.Lifted.consumeMsgs` should work with `StateT s IO`, the RabbitMQ haskell library actually discards the monadic state after each use. This means that if you do use that instance, you will not see changes made after the initial `consumeMsgs` call, including changes made by the callback itself. The callback is basically called with the same Monadic state every time - the state in which it was when the callback was registered.

This means that you can use it to pass global configuration state, but *not* to keep track of state between callback executions.